# Dihedral action on regular n-gon in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to represent the action of the dihedral group(D_{2n} on the regular n-gon in tikz, specifically the action of D_10 on the pentagon. I am hoping to do this by having a labelling and colouring of the nodes to represent how it responds to reflections and rotations.

I'm very new to tikz (I've only ever needed tikz-cd in previous work) and so I'm making slow progress.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[help lines/.style={blue!30,very thin}, thicc/.style={very thick}]
        \draw[help lines]   (-3.9,-3.9) grid (3.9,3.9);

        \node[thicc] (1) at (450:2) [circle,draw,red,fill=red!50,label=right:$1$];
        \node[thicc] (2) at (378:2) [circle,draw,blue,fill=blue!50,label=right:$2$];   
        \node[thicc] (3) at (306:2) [circle,draw,green,fill=green!30,label=right:$3$];    
        \node[thicc] (4) at (234:2) [circle,draw,orange,fill=red!30!yellow!30,label=right:$4$];
        \node[thicc] (5) at (162:2) [circle,draw,purple,fill=red!50!blue,label=right:$5$];

        \draw[thicc] (1) -- (2) -- (3) -- (4) -- (5) -- (1) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

I would aim for each node to have a different colour and label (labelling 1-5), and then redraw the same shape but reflected in the line through (say) vertex 2 (probably with a dashed line to indicate the line of symmetry), i.e. corresponding to the permutation (13)(45), and some rotation, say (13524).

Is this the best way to do this? I tried \foreach but I wasn't sure how to use the syntax correctly to get the different colours for each node etc. I would also like to scale the nodes to be bigger, and have the labels appear outside oft he circle (rather than at some fixed orientation.

Am I on the right lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For that it probably makes sense to store the pentagon in a pic and then subject this to the transformations. In order to have the labels always upright, one may want to use `transform shape=false`. It is arguably also more convenient to store the colors in lists and work with foreach loops. Of course, the reflection w.r.t. a rotated axis is the series of operations

```
rotate, reflect, inverse rotate
```

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[help lines/.style={blue!30,very thin},
pics/pentagon/.style={code={
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=5,minimum size=4cm,draw]
        (5gon){};
 \foreach \X in {1,...,5}
  {\pgfmathsetmacro{\myfillcolor}{{\LstFillCols}[mod(\X-1,5)]}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydrawcolor}{{\LstDrawCols}[mod(\X-1,5)]}
  \path (5gon.center) -- (5gon.corner \X) 
    node[circle,draw=\mydrawcolor,red,fill=\myfillcolor]{} 
    node[pos=1.2,transform shape=false](\X){\X};}}}]
 thicc/.style={very thick}]
 \edef\LstFillCols{"red!50","blue!50","green!30","red!30!yellow!30","red!50!blue"}
 \edef\LstDrawCols{"red","blue","green","orange","purple"}
 \draw[help lines]   (-3.9,-3.9) grid (3.9,3.9);
 \pic{pentagon};
 \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
  \draw[help lines]   (-3.9,-3.9) grid (3.9,3.9);
  \begin{scope}[rotate=72,xscale=-1,rotate=-72,transform shape]
   \draw[dashed] (162:3.9) -- (162+180:3.9); % symmetry axis
   \pic{pentagon};
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The advantage of this approach is that it can be used for arbitrary n.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[help lines/.style={blue!30,very thin},
 pics/ngon/.style={code={\tikzset{ngon/.cd,#1}
  \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ngon/n},
  minimum size=4cm,draw,ngon/border] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ngon/name}){};
   \foreach \X in {1,...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ngon/n}}
   {\pgfmathsetmacro{\myfillcolor}{{\LstFillCols}[mod(\X-1,5)]}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydrawcolor}{{\LstDrawCols}[mod(\X-1,5)]}
   \path (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ngon/name}.center) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ngon/name}.corner \X) 
    node[circle,draw=\mydrawcolor,fill=\myfillcolor,ngon/nodes]{} 
    node[pos=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ngon/label pos},transform shape=false](\X){\X};
    }
    }},flip about/.style={/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro{\posangle}{%
    -1*iseven(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ngon/n})*180/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ngon/n}+%
    (#1-1)*360/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ngon/n}},
    rotate=\posangle,xscale=-1,rotate=-1*\posangle},
    ngon/.cd,n/.initial=5,border/.style={very thick},nodes/.style={very thick},
    name/.initial={ngon},label pos/.initial=1.2,
    angle of/.code 2 args=\pgfmathsetmacro{#2}{%
    -1*iseven(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ngon/n})*180/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ngon/n}+%
    (#1-1)*360/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ngon/n}}]
 \edef\LstFillCols{"red!50","blue!50","green!30","red!30!yellow!30","red!50!blue"}
 \edef\LstDrawCols{"red","blue","green","orange","purple"}
 \draw[help lines]   (-3.9,-3.9) grid (3.9,3.9);
 \pic{ngon={n=5}};
 \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
  \draw[help lines]   (-3.9,-3.9) grid (3.9,3.9);
  \begin{scope}[ngon/n=5,flip about=2,transform shape]
   \pgfkeys{tikz/ngon/angle of={2}{\myangle}}
   \draw[dashed] (\myangle+90:3.9) -- (\myangle+270:3.9); % symmetry axis
   \pic{ngon};
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
 % second example
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-8cm]
 \draw[help lines]   (-3.9,-3.9) grid (3.9,3.9);
 \pic{ngon={n=8}};
 \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
  \draw[help lines]   (-3.9,-3.9) grid (3.9,3.9);
  \begin{scope}[ngon/n=10,flip about=3,transform shape]
   \pgfkeys{tikz/ngon/angle of={3}{\myangle}}   
   \draw[dashed] (\myangle+90:3.9) -- (\myangle+270:3.9); % symmetry axis
   \pic{ngon};
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
 % third example
 % second example
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-16cm,ngon/.cd,n=5,
 nodes/.style={inner sep=2ex},label pos=1.4]
 \draw[help lines]   (-3.9,-3.9) grid (3.9,3.9);
 \pgfkeys{tikz/ngon/angle of={1}{\myangleA}}
 \pgfkeys{tikz/ngon/angle of={2}{\myangleB}}  
 \pic{ngon};
 \draw[semithick,-latex] (90+\myangleA:3.5) 
 arc(90+\myangleA:90+\myangleB:3.5);
 \begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
  \draw[help lines]   (-3.9,-3.9) grid (3.9,3.9);
  \begin{scope}[flip about=2,transform shape]
   \pgfkeys{tikz/ngon/angle of={2}{\myangle}}
   \draw[dashed] (\myangle+90:3.9) -- (\myangle+270:3.9); % symmetry axis
   \pic{ngon};
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this code, there is a code `ngon/n` which determines the number of vertices of the regular polygon. (There are other keys that determine the style of lines, nodes and the name.) And there is an operation `flip about=m` which is nothing but the above-mentioned sequence of rotation, reflection and inverse rotation, which reflects the polygon about an axis that runs through one its `m`th corner and the center. For your convenience there is also a key `ngon/angle of` that computes the angle of the `m`th corner (Ti*k*Z has different conventions depending on whether the number of corners is even or odd).

Comment: This looks great. One further query for the moment: how would I go about adding in a circular arc from the first vertex to the nth that sits just outside of the n-gon (to indicate a rotation, in a similar manner to the dashed line denoting the reflection)?

Comment: I would also like to scale the nodes up slightly. I can do this using `minimum size` but then the labels are not spaced appropriately. I tried using `label distance` but I don't know where to put this command in your syntax.

Comment: @Ben That's a good point, I should have thought about the label position. Now it is in, along with an example that uses it, and also has an arc.